# Kentor SAML SSO Logout Issue

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, kentor-authservices

I have configured kentor single logout properly as mention in the kentor document for a single adfs. But when it came to deployment in client, they have got a different adfs setup.

Client Setup(May be ADFS Proxy not sure)
from our application when we type a specific domain. It redirects to a common sso domain (xxx.domain.com) from their we can select the area, each area has got different adfs servers(yyy.domain.com, ttt.domain.com) etc that is handled internally.

When we login it works, How to logout the particular area adfs domain without choosing individual area domains. The same configuration what i have setup with single adfs didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the flow is App --> ADFS (SP) --> Multiple ADFS (IDP)

If this is a SAML flow the app would send a logout to ADFS and ADFS would attempt to logout at the IDP based on a context cookie that knows which IDP to send the logout request to.

So, this should be handled automatically. If not, please file a request with MSFT support.

Also tweet to my twitter alias below for more questions.

Thanks
//Sam (Twitter: @MrADFS)